# setTitle() not changing the title

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

So, here is my doGet()

```
function doGet(e) {

  if (getDataInScriptCache("local") == null) {

    outputHTML = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("INTERFACE/ACESSO/AcessoHTML")
    return outputHTML
    .evaluate()
    .setTitle("Portaria")
    
  }

  else if (getDataInScriptCache("local") == "login") {

    outputHTML = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("INTERFACE/ACESSO/AcessoHTML")
    return outputHTML
    .evaluate()
    .setTitle("Portaria")
    

  }

  else if (getDataInScriptCache("local") == "main") {

      outputHTML = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("INTERFACE/MAIN/mainHTML")
      return outputHTML
      .evaluate()
      .setTitle("Portaria")

  }
}
```

I can create the page as it should do, but the title isn't changing at all

I tried to put the setTitle() before the evaluate, after the evaluate, before and after the return... But nothing works

Comment: Please add a [mcve]: simplify the doGet code and add the code of a .html file with the mininum code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("INTERFACE/ACESSO/AcessoHTML").evaluate().setTitle();
```

Comment: It's worked... But then how can i do also a setFaviconUrl()?

Comment: Look at these methods.  Perhaps one of the will be of some interest to you [methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output)

Comment: The thing is that return ends the function and thus I can't use it twice. I can set the title but I can't set the faviconurl at the same time

Comment: Don't use return until the end.